# Why isn't reversed() implemented for all collections?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is `iter()` implemented for all collections whereas `reversed()` isn't (e.g. dicts and sets don't implement it)? As the doc says `reversed()` returns a simple reverse iterator...

Comment: a dict is not a sequence, you cannot slice or index a dict which is required for a sequence

Comment: Dictionaries and sets aren't ordered, so "reverse" has no sensible meaning.

Comment: @jonrsharpe but accorting to you thinking `__iter__` shouldn't be implemented too, because as you said they are not ordered

Comment: You can get all the keys from a dict or set one after the other, so they implement `__iter__`.  But the order is arbitrary.  Using "reversed" implies that you care about the order, because you want it different than the default order.  But the default order is arbitrary, so it makes no sense to ask for a different order.

Comment: You can reverse the iteration if you're explicit about it (e.g. `reversed(d.keys())` will work, although as you shouldn't rely on the forward order you shouldn't rely on the backward order either!), but `reversed` only works on sequences (which dictionaries and sets aren't) or objects implementing `__reversed__` (which dictionaries and sets don't) - see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed).

Comment: If `s` is a set, you can always get the sorted sequence of elements of otherwise unordered collection using the `sorted(s)`. And then you can also get the reversed iterator as `reversed(sorted(s))`. The only inefficiency is that `sorted()` must build in-memory copy of the set elements for sorting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dictionaries and sets are not ordered. This is easy to overlook when you consider that iteration over them is supported... but one cannot assume any particular order in which iter() will provide items from sets and dictionaries, so it would not make sense to define a way to reverse this order.